# How to activate a terminal window after opening (and closing) NSOpenPanel requestor from a CLI app?

Tags: macos, terminal, appkit, nsopenpanel

I have a command line application running in a terminal and I want to be able use AppKit file requestor.
In the C code I initialise the AppKit using:

```objectivec
[NSApplication sharedApplication];
[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory]; // no additional window in the Dock
[NSApp setDelegate: my_app_delegate];
```

To open a dialog I then call from the C side such a function:

```objectivec
void request_file(void) {
    NSOpenPanel* openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = YES;

    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]; // to activate the dialog
    [openPanel makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

    [openPanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        if (result==NSModalResponseOK) {
            // do something with URLs
        }
        [NSApp stopModal];
    }];
    [openPanel runModal];
}
```

It works, but after closing the requestor, I must manually click with the mouse back on the terminal window to continue typing there.

**Is there some way how to activate the terminal window automatically after stopping the modal loop?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that I can use `NSRunningApplication` like:

```objectivec
void request_file(void) {
    // store currently active application so it can be reactivated later
    NSRunningApplication* wasRunningApp = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] frontmostApplication];

    NSOpenPanel* openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = YES;

    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]; // to activate the dialog
    [openPanel makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

    [openPanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        if (result==NSModalResponseOK) {
            // do something with URLs
        }
        [NSApp stopModal];

        // try to reactivate the previous application
        [wasRunningApp activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
    }];
    [openPanel runModal];
}
```